# Error: Connection error: Connection is not open on send()

Tags: web3js

After a few hours the socket to Infura seems to drop and we get the error, `Error: Connection error: Connection is not open on send()` Why does this happen or what is the best way to solve it?

version: 1.0.0-beta.52

This is how the app connects.

```
const contractConfig = require('./contract_config.js')

if (process.argv[3] == 'ropsten') {
  var network = 'ropsten';
} else {
  var network = 'main'
}
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(contractConfig[network].url));
```

Comment: Are we suppoed to guess the contents of your `contract_config.js` and the value of `process.argv[3]`???

Comment: The standard Infura web socket url `wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws/v3/KEY`. It works for some hours before the error. Maybe this would be better posted in a github issue.

Comment: Ah forgot to search github. https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1965#issuecomment-437269711

Answer (score 0):

I know that error happened on web3, but I got here even though searching for the solution on ethers. It can help others.

If you are using an overloaded function with ethers, you need to specify this function.

Example:

```
// initialize(string _name, string _symbol);
contract.initialize(name, symbol).then( ... );
contract["initialize(string,string)"](name, symbol).then( ... );

// initialize(string _name, string _symbol, address _registry);
contract["initialize(string,string,address)"](name, symbol, address).then( ... );

// initialize(string _sender);
contract["initialize(string)"](sender).then( ... );

// initialize();
contract["initialize()"]().then( ... );
```

Specifying the function works for me.

More info: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/407#issuecomment-458329708